# streaming a .mov to the browser as it's being written

Tags: ruby, selenium, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm using the [headless](https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless) and [selenium-webdriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Ruby-Bindings) gems to create a video:

```rb
# require gems
  require 'headless'
  require 'selenium-webdriver'

# start headless
  headless = Headless.new
  headless.start
  headless.video.start_capture

# use selenium
  driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)
  driver.navigate.to("http://google.com")
  puts driver.title

# exit headless and save video
  headless.video.stop_and_save("test.mov")
  headless.destroy
```

This produces a `test.mov` video.

In this example, I have a finalized `.mov` file which I could the  push to the browser if I wished.

But I'm hoping there's a way to stream is as it's being created.

If it helps, `headless` accepts configuration arguments for `ffmpeg`.

Comment: This [may](http://video.stackexchange.com/a/18179/1871) help.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks that is helpful. I'm making a little progress - I've figured out how to make `headless` output mp4 videos, which according to that link I should be able to stream. I'm giving it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mov can not be streamed live. It requires a frame index (moov) to be written to the file. The index can not be built until every frame is processed. mov can be pseudo streamed after it it completely written. For a streaming format you must use fragmented mp4 (like dash) or a protocol like webrtc.

Comment: Ok, this is helpful. I'm now trying to figure out how to produce a fragmented mp4 with the `headless` gem I'm using. I just posted a follow-up question: [produce-a-fragmented-mp4-with-the-headless-gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38154440/produce-a-fragmented-mp4-with-the-headless-gem)